# SIM900 email send recive Firmware > 1137B11SIM900M64 ST?

Tags: sim

I just received what I believe is the latest version of firmware SIM900, 1137B11SIM900M64 ST. I did the upgrade and
I try to implement without any results, commands reported in SIM900_Email_AT_Command_Manual_V1.02

One thing I find curious is that these new commands are not reported in the manual very last 1.05 of AT commands

Already beyond anyone had any experience with this version/, can tell where the problem is, or is it that there is a newer version of firmaware have to implement?

for each command to implement the response is ERROR. this is what tells me that probably this is not implemented

for example: cmmd resp

AT+EMAILCID? > ERROR

AT+EMAILCID=? > ERROR

AT+EMAILCID=1 > ERROR

and thus to each and every one of the commands reported in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1137B11SIM900M64 ST not support E-mail.
need a special version of the firmware

1137B10SIM900M64_ST_Email_TEST_20111103 - test only version